# rendering .hbs templates in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I'm looking at an Ember demo project https://github.com/kagemusha/ember-rails-devise-demo that uses templates endeding in .hbs. Normally in Ember, you declare the template by attaching, for example, `id='about'` for the `about` route. However, none of the templates ending in .hbs in this project use an id. How does Ember know which template to render?

Example template

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="brand strong">{{#linkTo 'home'}}Ember-Rails-Devise{{/linkTo}}</div>
      <ul class="nav">
          <li>{{#linkTo help}}Help{{/linkTo}}</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="btn-group pull-right">
        {{#if isAuthenticated}}
            <button class="btn" {{action logout}}>Logout</button>
        {{else}}
            {{view App.MenuItem href="#/login" label="Login" }}
            {{view App.MenuItem href="#/registration" label="Register"}}
        {{/if}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember.js uses naming convension.

When we define routes in ember app, we tell Ember which controller will respond at which path and which template will be rendered:

```
App.Router.map ()->
  @resource 'posts'
```

Here we have:

```
URL         /posts
Route Name  posts
Controller  PostsController
Route       PostsRoute
Template    post
```

`PostsController` controller will render `posts.hbs` template. This is pretty similar to Rails. Of cause we can customise almost everything here.

Comment: More info on the naming convention can be found in the guides - http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/